# Problem in getting responsive Google map and it's showing two scroll bars after adding

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want a responsive google map in one of my section . it's not responsive and it's showing two scroll bars in the page. I want in a full page width so I have take container fluid with a 12 columns.

You can see the code below.

```
<section class="googleMap">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="map">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?anylocation" width="2000" height="450"  allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Comment: Update the map width to 100%

Answer (score 1):

First of all, remove the width and height attributes from iframe tag. And add css rule to iframe with 100% width and height 100% to take its parent container height. (if you want it's to cover the whole screen use 99.5vh in height). Here use the code for reference :

```css
body {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}
iframe {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  border:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
}
```

```html
<section class="googleMap">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xl-12 col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
    <div class="map">
      <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?anylocation"  allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy"></iframe>
    </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please remove the properties `width="2000"` and add `style="width: 100%;"` on `<iframe>` element.

**Code :-**

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?anylocation" height="450"  allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" style="width: 100%;"></iframe>
```